# XGBModel' object has no attribute 'evals_result_'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to use xgboost on a dataset. I have seen the same syntax in various blogs but I am getting an error while calling clf.evals_result()
here is my code

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae

evals_result ={}
eval_s = [(x, y),(xval,yval)]

clf = xgb(n_estimators=100,learning_rate=0.03,tree_method='gpu_hist',lamda=0.1,eval_metric='mae',eval_set=eval_s,early_stopping_rounds=0,evals_result=evals_result)

clf.fit(x,y) 

r = clf.evals_result()
```

here is error I am receiving

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-2d6867968043> in <module>
      1 
----> 2 r = clf.evals_result()
      3 
      4 p = clf.predict(xval)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in evals_result(self)
    399          'validation_1': {'logloss': ['0.41965', '0.17686']}}
    400         """
--> 401         if self.evals_result_:
    402             evals_result = self.evals_result_
    403         else:

AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'evals_result_'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got exactly the same error, the solution it's to pass the eval_set to the fit function and not in the creation of the classifier

```
clf.fit(x,y,eval_set=eval_s)
```

Then you can run clf.evals_result()

Comment: This is great. Such a common error avoided.